# How to delete 4 words before cursor in vim?

Tags: vim

I would also like to know if there are other ways to delete 4 words after the cursor.

I know `4de` and `4dw` delete 4 words after the cursor and `4db` will delete 4 words in front of the cursor, but when I'm in the middle of a word like below:

```
// SO|ME RANDOM CODE HERE
```

the result from running `4de` and `4dw` is:

```
// SO|
```

instead of deleting all 4 words.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: just add a `b` in front of the command and you're done ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`4dw` deletes using a text motion: it is four times "delete from here to where I jump by `w`", which deletes the end of the word four times.

Use text objects instead: `4daw` is four times "delete a word", or delete four words.